# Django notification giving error for other model

Tags: python, django, django-notification

Following code is working for comment section.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
from django.db.models import signals
from notification import models as notification

def new_comment(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    # remove this if-block if you want notifications for comment edit too
    if not created:
        return None

    context = {
        'comment': instance,
        'site': Site.objects.get_current(),
    }
    recipients = []

    # add all users who commented the same object to recipients
    for comment in instance.__class__.objects.for_model(instance.content_object):
        if comment.user not in recipients and comment.user != instance.user:
            recipients.append(comment.user)

    # if the commented object is a user then notify him as well
    if isinstance(instance.content_object, models.get_model('auth', 'User')):
        # if he his the one who posts the comment then don't add him to recipients
        if instance.content_object != instance.user and instance.content_object not in recipients:
            recipients.append(instance.content_object)

    notification.send(recipients, 'friends_invite', context)

signals.post_save.connect(new_comment, sender=models.get_model('comments', 'Comment'))
```

But when we implement the same code for other custome model comment then it giving error at the time of entering the record in model.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
from django.db.models import signals
from notification import models as notification

def create_notice_types(app, created_models, verbosity, **kwargs):
        notification.create_notice_type("friends_invite", _("Invitation Received"), _("you have received an invitation"))
        notification.create_notice_type("friends_accept", _("Acceptance Received"), _("an invitation you sent has been accepted"))

signals.post_syncdb.connect(create_notice_types, sender=notification)

    def new_comment(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        # remove this if-block if you want notifications for comment edit too
        if not created:
            return None

        context = {
            'gufeed_feedcomment': instance,
        }
        recipients = []

        # add all users who commented the same object to recipients
        for comment in instance.__class__.objects.for_model(instance.content_object):
            if comment.user not in recipients and comment.user != instance.user:
                recipients.append(comment.user)

        # if the commented object is a user then notify him as well
        if isinstance(instance.content_object, models.get_model('auth', 'User')):
            # if he his the one who posts the comment then don't add him to recipients
            if instance.content_object != instance.user and instance.content_object not in recipients:
                recipients.append(instance.content_object)

        notification.send(recipients, 'friends_invite', context)

    signals.post_save.connect(new_comment, sender=models.get_model('gufeed_feedcomment', 'FeedHottPoint'))
```

Note: we are taking friends_invite notification type this is already created

**ERROR:**
AttributeError at /gufeed/comment/add/
'Manager' object has no attribute 'for_model'

Comment: I don't understand what `instance.__class__.objects.for_model(instance.content_object)` is supposed to be doing. Is that trying to use ContentType? If so, it's a very bizarre way of doing so.