# Django send email to the user when a specific field on a model has bean changed

Tags: django, email, model

I want to send an email to a user on model change.
Here is what I have : I have a model called package containing a field status and a field owner , I want to send an email to the owner of the package when the status is changed.
Is there a way to do so ? 
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Signals might help you out.

Think of Signal methods as code that is always executed before or after an operation on a model; e.g, a `pre_save()` signal is called just before a record is saved to database, `post_delete()` is called just after a record is deleted from the database.

Implement a `pre_save()` signal on the model and get the value of `status` field from the database before saving. Check if this previous value is different from the one for the corresponding status field in `update_fields`. If so, email the user.

Here are the docs for [pre_save()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save)
and [Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/signals/).

Here's a tutorial I followed while learning Signals:
[How to Create Django Signals
 - SimpleIsBetterThanComplex](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Follow Shuai Xu's method to send an email, in the `pre_save()` method.

Answer (score 1):

When the event of changing status is triggered, send the email to the owner.

Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/email/

Or if your prefer the built-in notification:[How to use django-notification to inform a user when somebody comments on their post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603469/how-to-use-django-notification-to-inform-a-user-when-somebody-comments-on-their)