# notification feature for django project

Tags: django, notifications

I'm trying to add notification feature just like social network sites do something like: ( 'x user has add comment', ' x user has like your post' ..) and so on

I was searching for a guideline for this feature in django to follow up, I found this answer "[How to use django-notification to inform a user when somebody comments on their post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603469/how-to-use-django-notification-to-inform-a-user-when-somebody-comments-on-their)
" but since it's 6 years ago, some functions is deprecated and webpages links is down. And I believe since 6 years django community add some built-in feature make these things easier. the framework `django-notification` now become [pinax-notifications](https://github.com/pinax/pinax-notifications) and as I read it's based on email notification - that not what i'm looking for-.

For example let's say my current project has 3 classes in models as following :

```
class user(models.mode):
.....

class post(models.mode):
user = foreignkey(user)
.....

class comment(models.mode):
user = foreignkey(user)
post = foreignkey(post)
.....

class likse(models.mode):
user = foreignkey(user)
post = foreignkey(post)
comment = foreignkey(comment)
.....
```

Is there any guideline for modifying the project to add-on notification feature ? btw, i'm working on django 1.11 and python 3

Answer (score 0):

In Views, use:-

```
from django.contrib import messages
```

Inside A function,add

```
errormessage="type error message here"
messages.error(request,errormessage ,extra_tags='alert alert-danger')
```

extra_tags is to give class in the template

In template

```
  {% if messages %}
          <ul class="messages">
          {% for message in messages %}
          <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
          {% endfor %}
          </ul>
  {% endif %}
```

For reference go to 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/messages/